# Java file copy fails

Tags: java

I have written a very simple Java program to copy a file passed as an argument to the /tmp directory. The program produces several Java exceptions.

```
public class CopyFile {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fqp2File = "";

    if (new File(args[0]).isFile()) {
       fqp2File = args[0];
    }
    else {
       System.out.println("Passed argument is not a file");
    }
    copy(fqp2File, "/tmp");
}

private static boolean copy(String from, String to) throws IOException{
    Path src = Paths.get(from);
    Path dest = Paths.get(to);
    try {
        Files.copy(src, dest, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.format("I/O Error when copying file");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

When I run this program I get these errors:

```
java -jar CopyFile.jar /home/downloads/dfA485MVSZ.ncr.pwgsc.gc.ca.1531160874.13500750
I/O Error when copying filejava.nio.file.FileSystemException: /tmp:
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:103)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:114)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:119)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copy(UnixCopyFile.java:578)
        at  sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.copy(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:265)
        at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1285)
        at ca.gc.ssc.gems.esnap.cipo.CopyFile.copy(CopyFile.java:39)
        at ca.gc.ssc.gems.esnap.cipo.CopyFile.main(CopyFile.java:31)
```

Comment: What argument did you try passing it?

Answer (score 3):

To test your code I used `C:/tmp/test.txt;` as your `args[0]`.  I fixed the issue by giving the output a filename to write to shown below:

```
Path dest = Paths.get(to);
```

to

```
Path dest = Paths.get(to, "test2.txt");
```

And it now successfully copied the file into that name, you can modify the filename however you want or add logic to change filename automatically.

Comment: Note that instead of doing `Paths.get(to + "/test2.txt")` you can also use `Paths.get(to, "test2.txt")` and let the class figure out the path separators for you.

Comment: Thanks Ill edit it, I assume you mean `to` without quotes though!

Comment: Thanks, as a test I modified my code to use `Path dest = Paths.get(to, "test2.txt");`  Does this mean that a directory cannot be use as the destination?

Comment: You can modify the code to generate a name automatically based on the input name if you want, which would effectively be only using the directory to create a file.  You need to name it _something_ though.